# jqGrid is not a function when loadState function call - using spring thymeleaf and jqGrid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jqgrid, thymeleaf

I use Spring boot thymeleaf and jqGrid in my application. Everything works correct until I call loadState function from jqGrid plugin for loading state of cols order, filtering and so on. 
Columng orders loads but data not load and in console of browser I see 
*TypeError: table.jqGrid is not a function*

```
 $.jgrid.saveState("table");
```

works fine and saves state of column but

```
$.jgrid.loadState("table");
```

doesn't work. Did anyone have the same problem?

P.S. My code with resources loads in this order:

```
css for jqgrid

<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/grid.locale-ru.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/ui.multiselect.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/jquery.jqGrid.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/chosen.jquery.min.js}"></script>

my js file with jqgrid table
```

Here some example from my project which works fine:

```
var options = {
    datastr: grid_data,
    datatype: 'jsonstring',
    jsonReader: {
        root: 'gridModel',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    height: 'auto',
    editurl: URL,
    colNames: collnames,
    colModel: [
        {
            name: 'myac', index: '', width: 100, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
            formatter: 'actions',
            formatoptions: {
                keys: true,
                delbutton: false,//disable delete button
                editformbutton: true,
                editOptions: editOpt
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'id',
            label: 'ID',
            index: 'id',
            formatter: 'integer',
            width: 40,
            hidden: true,
            editable: true,
            editoptions: {disabled: true, size: 5}
        },

        {
            name: 'history',
            label: 'history',
            index: 'history',
            hidden: true,
            editable: true
        },
        {
            name: 'name',
            stype: 'text',
            label: 'name',
            index: 'name',
            editable: true,
            editOptions: {disabled: true},
            align: 'center'
        },
        {
            name: 'value',
            stype: 'text',
            index: 'value',
            editable: true,
            align: 'center'
        },
        {
            name: 'description',
            label: 'description',
            index: 'description',
            stype: 'text',
            align: 'center',
            editable: true
        }
    ],

    pager: pager,
    storeNavOptions : true,
    toppager: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    rowNum: 15,
    rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
    altRows: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    subGrid: true,
    loadComplete: function () {

    },
};
```

works incorrect:

```
table.jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: true
    },
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: colNames,
    colModel: colModel,
    url: URL_DATA,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    forceFit: true,
    pager: pager,
    toppager: true,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
    loadonce: true,
    navOptions: {reloadGridOptions: {fromServer: true}},
    loadComplete: function () {
        var table = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            updatePagerIcons(table);
            enableTooltips(table);
        }, 0);
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        var idarray = table.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        if (idarray.length > 0) {
            var firstid = table.jqGrid('getDataIDs')[0];
            table.setSelection(firstid);
        }
    }
});

$(window).triggerHandler('resize.jqGrid');//trigger window resize to make the grid get the correct size
```

Comment: What is the id of the grid? Is the id of the grid = 'table' or something else?

Comment: @TonyTomov, yes id if the grid is 'table'. it works fine untill i call loadState function

Answer (score 0):

It will be a good if you prepare a example.

The **loadState** does not load if the data string in the local storage can not be found or as of your case the table id can not be found in the place where you call loadState. Be a sure that the table with id='table' exists in the place where you call the loadState.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Id exists. I found that the reason why I get error it's because my data loads dynamicly from the server. I have another table and loadState works fine with it. The only difference between tables is data loading. I add example to my question. Please, if you know how to fix loadstate for dynamic data - let me know.

Comment: It seems to me you do not use Guriddo jqGrid, but free-jqGrid. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help in this case. I can only do this for Guriddo jqGrid.